# Check if sub-object exists before using it

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

In order to prevent using an object's value that doesn't exist (which would throw an error), I usually do something like this:

```
if(apple.details){
   // do something with apple.details
}
```

and it normally works fine. But if it's about a "object's object's value", like `apple.details.price`, that doesn't work, because if not even `.details` exists, the `if()` would throw an error.

What can I do or is there generally a better way to do this?

Comment: try `if(apple.details && apple.details.price)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Since 2020:**

The best way to solve this is using the [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) Operator

```
if(apple?.details) // Undefined if apple does not exist
```

Suggestion of `lodash` is no longer required when using runtime compatible with ES2020 i.e. [Most browsers today & node>14.5](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----)

Answer (score 3):

You can do chain:

```
if (apple && apple.details && apple.details.price) { ... }
```

But it's not convenient if the chain is long. Instead you can use [lodash.get method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get)
With lodash:

```
if (get(apple, 'details.price')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try solution of @Sphinx

I would also suggest _.get(apple, 'details.price') of [lodash](http://lodash.com), but surely it is not worth to include whole library for simple project or few tasks.

_.get() function also prevents from throwing error, when even apple variable is not defined (undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check each parent object prior to checking the nested child object, i.e., `if (a && a.b && a.b.c) {}`

If you're using LoDash, you can use the [`_.get` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get) with an optional default:

```
let obj = {'a': {'b': {'c': 42} } };
let result = _.get(obj, 'a.b.c'); // 42
let result2 = _.get(obj, 'a.b.d'); // undefined
let result3 = _.get(obj, 'a.c.d', null); // null
```

If you're not using LoDash, you can implement a simplified version of `_.get` [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40149923/59111).

Comment: This would provide more value if the final sentence was added as comment on the selected answer.

Comment: @JonSG odd perspective. All of the answers here were posted within minutes of each other, as often happens on this site. None were selected as the answer at the time of this post.

Comment: Don't get your hackles up!  There is now an "accepted answer" that is not this one.  Your final sentence would be a valuable addition to the "accepted answer".  I did not say you copied anyone did I?  Frankly I expect more from someone with 72k rep.